# Why does my typer's print make a new line for every character?

Tags: python, string, printing, newline

I am running python 3.X, in console.
Why does my typer's print make a new line for every character?
Here is the code:

```
import msvcrt as m
def wait():
    m.getch()

print(" ")
string = """
code
"""

for i in string:
    wait()
    print(str(i).replace("\n", ""))
```

Here is the output:

```
c
o
d
e
```

Here is the output I want:

```
code
```

Comment: Take some time to look over the docs before asking here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out on my own.
having this:

```
print(someString, end=anything)
```

causes the output to not load in. This is because the code is buffering, and holds onto the output. My solution was to refresh my output every print, using *sys.stdout.flush().* Here is the code that lets the output go:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Here is my final "pretend-typer" code:

```
import msvcrt as m
import sys
def wait():
    m.getch()

print(" ")
stringy = """code"""

for i in stringy:
    wait()
    s = i
    print(s, end="")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Replace stringy with whatever you want the user to type. This does not work in emulators such as PyCharm or Eclipse, unless you run in console mode. This **needs** to be in a console.

Answer (score 1):

The [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function has an argument called `end` which is by default... You guessed it! `'\n'`.

If you don't want to have the default new-line, you can do:

```
print(..., end="")
```

So doing:

```
string = """
code
"""

for i in string:
    print(i, end="")
```

Gives:

```
code
```

Comment: It's blank when I print with end="", until I reach the end of the string.

Comment: @DustinMachat Try adding `flush=True` to `print`.

Answer (score 0):

`print` takes an optional keyword argument `end`, whose value defaults to `\n'`. You need to change that to the empty string. It's also simpler to just ignore `i == "\n"` rather than replace it with `""`.

```
for i in string():
    wait()
    if i != "\n":
        print(i, end='')
```

Comment: It prints nothing until you reach the end of the string.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering.

Comment: You may also simply want to use `m.putch` instead of `print`.

Answer (score 0):

Print has a flush method built-in with Python 3.3 and later. If using Python 3.3+ is an option, you should be able to skip calling `sys.stdout.flush()`.

```
import msvcrt as m

def wait():
    m.getch()

print(" ")
my_string = "code"

for c in my_string:
    wait()
    print(str(c), end='', flush=True)
```